# Program to make the Java client wait until receiving a response from the server

Tags: java, blocking, json-rpc

Currently, I am developing a simple WebRTC application, in which the client and server communicate with each other through RPC. Because of its blocking nature, in essence, meaning if I have a request and send it to the server, I need to wait till I receive the response. I have trouble how to make a client wait till receiving a response from the server then move on. Initially, I did some things like `Thread.sleep()`, or using `ExecutorService` and `CountDownLatch`, they are working, but the responsive of the program is really downgraded, and I have no idea how long the client should sleep for a response from the server. I want to use `CompleableFuture` in this case, but I still don't have any idea how can I use this in my context, any help is much appreciated!

Here is the client code:

```java
@Override
public CompletableFuture<SessionDescription> join(String sid, String uid, SessionDescription offer) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        JsonRpcRequestMessage rpcMsg = new JsonRpcRequestMessage();
        rpcMsg.setJsonrpc("2.0");
        rpcMsg.setId(uuid);
        rpcMsg.setMethod("join");
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("offer", offer);
        params.put("sid", sid);
        params.put("uid", uid);
        rpcMsg.setParams(params);
        try {
            String rpcText = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rpcMsg);
            webSocket.send(rpcText); // here the client sends a text message to the server, then immediately it has to wait to receive a response from the server
           // should I use Thread.sleep(n), or something?
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    // here I need to return whatever server responses when I send the text above.

}
```

Comment: ever set a timeout?

Comment: What do you mean? can you answer my question then I can accept your answer?

Comment: 'I have no idea how long the client should sleep for a response from the server' --- usually we can set timeout in client side. i'm not familiar with socket in java, though. and can you specify which websocket library are you using?

Comment: I'm using OkHttp library

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the client's view, then create a `CompletableFuture` by the (delayed) server-response and eventually enable the client's view again, when the CompletableFeature is done.

So your method would look similiar to the following:

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<SessionDescription> join(String sid, String uid, SessionDescription offer) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() => {
          String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
          JsonRpcRequestMessage rpcMsg = new JsonRpcRequestMessage();
          rpcMsg.setJsonrpc("2.0");
          rpcMsg.setId(uuid);
          rpcMsg.setMethod("join");
          Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
          params.put("offer", offer);
          params.put("sid", sid);
          params.put("uid", uid);
          rpcMsg.setParams(params);
          try {
              String rpcText = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rpcMsg);
              webSocket.send(rpcText); 
          } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          // return the server-response here.
        });
}
```

and you would disable the client's view before calling it and enable it when the CompletableFuture is done:

```
// disable the view here
join(sid, uid, offer).thenAccept((serverResponse)=>{
   // enable the view here
});
```

This way you don't need to check for Future-Completion manually since you tell Java what to do when the Future is done.